# $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,\ldots,x_k$ being random signs that are independent |-> $\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k x_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n {b_k}^2$

Tags: probability, generating-functions, variance

$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,\ldots,x_k$ are random signs that are independent. (I suppose this means that $P(x_i=1)=0.5=P(x_i=−1))$

Does the following hold?

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k x_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n {b_k}^2$$
for $b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots,b_k\in\mathbb R$.

So variance is the second derivative of a generating function. And I supposed the generating function for $x_k$ would be $0.5t^1+0.5t^{-1}$? Doesn't seem right when i plug it in there.

Comment: It would be easier just to use the formula for the variance of a linear combination of r.v.'s , I would think.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties

Comment: @michael the question does not say antyhing but what i have posted. So I assume this will be probability generating function such that g(t)=$\sum p(i)*t^i$ and g'(t) is expectation with g''(t) being the vairance

Comment: How would i be able to compute cov(xi,xj)? thanks.

Comment: $g'(t)$ is a function, and the variance is a number, so they can't be the same thing.  The expectation is $g'(1),$ right?  What is the variance?

Comment: What is the covariance of two independent r.v.'s?

Comment: zero? i presume? and the variance should be 1 (since mean is 0)?

Comment: OHH so using the equation given on wiki, that gives the desired result? but could you explain how this question is related to generating functions? (this is what this problem's topic is under)

Comment: It is not. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

Since the $x_k$ are independent, the $b_kx_k$ are independent as well. Remember, that the variance of the sum of independent random variables is the same as the sum of the variances of those variables. Furthermore, for any $k$, it holds that $$Var(b_kx_k) = b_{k}^{2}Var(x_k) = b_k^2 (E(x_k^2)-E(x_k)^2)= b_k^2(1-0) = b_k^2 .$$

Combining all of the above statements, we get: $$ Var(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_kx_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}Var(b_kx_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k^2  .$$

So indeed the statement holds.